# Add data to pandas rolling mean without recalculating everything

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a pandas Series `series` with a lot of entries, now I calculate

```
series.rolling(window=25000,center=False).mean()
```

This may calculate a very long time, since it is a lot of data.
Now I want to add new data to this series (Data that is only available over time and not before the original calculation).
If I calculate the rolling mean again, it will take again a very long time, is there a way, to spped up the second calculation by reusing data from the first calculation? (Probably with another library)

Comment: You mean new series append to the original one ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have new `series`

```
r1=series.rolling(window=25000,center=False).mean()
r2=series.iloc[-2499:].append(new_series).rolling(window=25000,center=False).mean().dropna()
r=r1.append(r2)
```